# jQueryTools Scrollable - jumps to last image in circular mode

Tags: jquery-tools

[jQuery Scrollable](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/scrollable/) (with the navigator plugin) is showing the wrong slide when it first loads.

It behaves normally when I use it like this:

`$(".scrollable").scrollable({}).navigator();`

…but as soon I enable the 'circular' mode (to allow looping from the final slide back to the first):

`$(".scrollable").scrollable({ circular: true }).navigator();`

on page load, the *final* item is the *first* one show, even though item 1 **is** highlighted in the navigator.  If you go through the images, when you get to the final one, it's shown a second time, and you only see the actual first image at the beginning of the *second* loop.

Any suggestions?

Here's my HTML for completeness:

```
<div class="column two-thirds scrollable" id="scrollable">

<a class="prev browse left">Previous</a>

<div class="items">
        <div><img src="1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div><img src="2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div><img src="3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div><img src="4.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</div>

<a class="next browse right">Next</a>

<div class="naviWrapper">
 <div class="navi"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm just noticing the same issues. When you use circular, it clones the last item and drops it in the first spot, and it also clones the first item and drops it in the last spot. I assume this is so the animation can be smooth when clicking "prev" when the first item is in view, and when clicking "next" when the last item is in view. I,however, do not see the cloned item in the first spot. Try removing ".navigator()" first and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the same issue, suggesting that you replace your `<img>` tags with `<div>` tags that have a background image.
https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/issues/47

I could not do that as some of my images had image maps. However, all my images had the same dimensions, so I put in image dimensions, i.e.

```
<img width=730 height=360 alt="first image" src="/images/my-image.jpg" />
```

And that seems to have solved it.